# Alt-Tab sometimes switches out of full screen Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, alt-tab

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium locally and Windows 7 Enterprise remotely via Remote Desktop. The RD window is full screen. Sometimes, when I press Alt-Tab, it is processed by both the remote machine and my local machine. The result is that I get switched to another local window and when I switch back to the RD window, it has switched to another window as well.

This only happens sometimes. If I press Alt-Tab again after switching back to the RD window, it will work correctly. But if I wait about 10 seconds and then try again, the problem happens again.

My local Windows 7 is not patched to SP1, nor is the remote Windows 7.

Comment: I have subsequently patched both my local Windows 7 and the remote Windows 7 to Service Pack 1 and I'm still getting this problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the remote desktop connection application
2. Click the options button
3. Go to the local resources tab
4. There will be a box labeled keyboard
5. Set the option to "on the remote computer"

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: After doing this you can use the shortcuts suggested by @Josh to switch between windows in the RDC (i.e Alt + Insert or Alt + PageUp/PageDown)

Answer (score 2):

Sure-fire way to "alt tab" inside of an RDP session is to press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd>

Also, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> will do the same thing as you'd expect <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: Those keys do nothing.

Comment: This one was the fix for me in a Citrix-driven RDP environment where I could not edit the MSTSC client settings.

Answer (score 1):

These Shortcut Keys might help

- <kbd>Alt + PageUp</kbd>: Move between apps from left to right
- <kbd>Alt + PageDown</kbd>: Move between apps from right to left
- <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd>: Cycle through apps in the order that they were started