# Any shortcut for switching between Remote Desktop and local desktop?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

Normally in windows we use "ALT+TAB" to switch between windows.
So is there any shortcut for switching between my desktop and remote desktop.
I need it desperately.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/547067/while-in-a-remote-desktop-session-in-windows-7-alt-tab-to-go-back-to-the-host-m) appears to be a duplicate question which shows legitimate answers that were never confirmed by the user on the other question but appear to be what the OP is asking for. Since the answer was never verified, I am unable to flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1676184/1112954

Answer (score 6):

You've got two options:

1. Disable keyboard shortcuts capturing in mstsc.exe, and then use this shortcuts when inside RDP:
   [RDP Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Leave the capturing on, and then use CTRL+ALT+Break to exit full screen, and then you can use the shortcuts on your local computer as usual.