# Alt-tab back to the host while using TeamViewer?

Tags: remote, hotkeys, teamviewer, productivity

I've got a TeamViewer session open. I can alt-tab to it, but then all hotkeys are captured by the TeamViewer session. This is great, but I'd like to be able to 'escape' back to the host without using the mouse, perhaps using some special meta shortcut. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/547067/while-in-a-remote-desktop-session-in-windows-7-alt-tab-to-go-back-to-the-host-m) offers a solution using Windows RDP, but I the same key combinations don't seem to work in TeamViewer. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Just to rule out some possible alternatives, are shortcuts that use the Windows key captured by the session as well? (Win + Down Arrow for instance)

Comment: Yes, TeamViewer either sends key shortcuts or not, and selecting to send sends *all* of them, it appears. Programs such as Virtual Box will allow you to select a 'host key' that breaks you out. That's what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Looks like Scroll Lock will enable/disable sending shortcuts to remote system, so you could use it to disable sending hotkeys, then alt+tab locally, eventually go back to the remote window and Scroll Lock again to re-enable hotkeys on remote.

Comment: to panhandel, what do you mean about scroll lock working to do what the OP asks? I clicked it (both with and without the fn key my laptop keyboard had for that key), and it did NOT enable/disable Tv's sending of keys to the remote. Was so hopeful that it might.

Comment: Like the OP, I would LOVE to find such a capability to "leave the teamviewer remote" and have shortcuts again work on the local machine. As a keyboard guy, I've missed this feature daily since leaving logmein (when it dropped free support), which DID offer such a key combination, ctrl+alt.) VirtualBox also offers it, in its "host" key (which defaults to the right control key). And before any helpful TV users might chime in, we are AWARE that there is the menu option to enable/disable sending of keys to the remote. We're wanting a keystroke toggle to do it, on demand, not disabling it entirely.

Answer (score 4):

Since its 2020 and still no HostKey solution on TeamViewer - below little Autohotkey snippet worked:

1. Install Autohotkey..
2. Edit AutoHotkey file (under My Docs) on windows
3. Add snippet below
4. When Pressing ALT+' (to the left of the number 1), it will minimize the active window.

Tested with TeamViewer 15.1

```
; -------- ALT + ` 
; ----------- Minimize Active Window
!`::
    WinMinimize, A
  return
```

Comment: Finally, a workable solution! Thank you! This has been bugging me for years!

Comment: Excellent! Also love the fact you've assigned it to \`, conveniently located right above tab. I can alt-tab into TeamViewer and alt-` out of it in the blink of an eye :)

Comment: Can confirm, this solution works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but no mouse; tested in `Windows 10 host`, and `Windows 10 client`.

### Scenario

Suppose you have a tab open on your host, e.g. `notepad` (referred to as `original-non-teamviewer-tab`) while you are working in a teamviewer tab that controls your `Windows 10 client`:

### Solution:

`ctrl+alt+delete`

`down`

`down`

`down`

`down`

`enter` (switches back to host, opening `Task Manager`.)

`alt+tab+tab` (switches back to your `original non-teamviewer-tab`.)

`alt+tab` (switches back to `Task Manager`.)

`alt+F4` (closes `Task Manager` and switches back to your `original non-teamviewer-tab`.)

### Approach 0

If you are willing to accept `task manager` to remain as open tab you can reduce the minimal required number of sequential key presses from 10 to 8.

### Approach 1

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-alt-tab-on-teamviewer claims you can enable and disable `Sending key combinations` with `scroll lock`. That would reduce the amount of sequential keypresses to 2 in stead of 10. But I have not yet been unable to verify their solution.

### Approach 2

Alternatively you could make an autohotkey script of the solution and map it to a single key press.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that, in Windows 10, the key combination for switching desktop (`Ctrl+Win+Arrow_key`) is not being intercepted by TeamViewer.

So, my solution is to put TeamViewer in a separate virtual desktop and switch back to the main (or another one) with `Ctrl + Win + Arrow_key`

p.s. Be careful to start the key combination with the `Ctrl`

Comment: This is a brilliant find! Thanks a lot, you saved my time. TeamViewer should really learn from VMWare for its smooth interaction functionality

Comment: Actually, after a while TeamViewer started capturing Ctrl + Win + Arrow again. bummer..

Answer (score 0):

this is what did it for me:
go to teamviewer options -> remote control -> and disable "send key combinations"